# JavaFx8 Table, Row Selection: Change color if table view has not focus

Tags: javafx

How do I change the row selection color if the table view has not the focus ? I want that the color does not change if focus is lost.

My usecase is that I have a JavaFx dialog, in which the table view is embedded . The row selection can be influenced by a hotkey. If the user presses a hotkey, the row selection changes and I set the focus to the Ok button of the dialog. That works but the row selection highlighting color looks not good, then.

Comment: What do you have so far? Without any code it is all a bit abstract to give any advice.

Comment: @hotzst I have not tried anything so far, because I do not know the reason for the color change (if focus is lost). I guess it is maybe a separate css property ? I guess the reason for the 'bad looking' is that I use the dark theme. http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an external CSS file, do

```
.table-row-cell:filled:selected, .table-row-cell:filled > .table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%);
}
```

or, alternatively

```
.table-view {
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: -fx-selection-bar ;
}
```

and of course you could use the latter version to set the non-focused selection to any color you choose.

(You could also do it directly in Java with

```
tableView.setStyle("-fx-selection-bar-non-focused: -fx-selection-bar ;");
```

but I recommend putting it in a CSS file.)